# Tween an autoRotating camera (OrbitControls) from Point A to Point B

Tags: javascript, three.js, camera

I have a scene in which there is a planet (earth) at position `(0, 0, 0)` with a radius of `100`.

When the scene loads, the camera is positioned at `(0, 0, 600)` to make the planet appear to be further away, and after a few seconds the camera tweens to `(0, 150, 200)` to give the effect of the planet moving closer and being slightly cropped off the screen.

This works perfectly fine using Tween.js and the camera tweens to the exact correct position. However, I want the planet to appear to be rotating the whole time i.e. before, during, and after the tween, and so I am using `OrbitControls` with `autoRotate` set to `true`.

When I enable `autoRotate`, the camera tweens to a slightly wrong position which I assume is because `autoRotate` updates the `x` and `z` positions of the camera and so the tween is not moving from one exact position to another.

**So my question is**, how can I tween an autoRotating camera from one position to another correctly so that it ends up at the exact right coordinates and is rotating the entire time?

My animate function:

```
props.camera.animate = (duration = 2000) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        let { x: croppedX, y: croppedY, z: croppedZ } = settings.camera.croppedPosition;

        let from = {
            x: props.camera.position.x,
            y: props.camera.position.y,
            z: props.camera.position.z,
            lookAtX: tools.orbit.target.x,
            lookAtY: tools.orbit.target.y,
            lookAtZ: tools.orbit.target.z
        }

        let to = {
            x: croppedX,
            y: croppedY,
            z: croppedZ,
            lookAtX: 0,
            lookAtY: croppedY,
            lookAtZ: -1
        }

        let tween = new TWEEN.Tween(from)
            .to(to, duration)
            .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Sinusoidal.InOut)
            .onUpdate(function() {
                props.camera.position.set(from.x, from.y, from.z);
                tools.orbit.target.copy(new THREE.Vector3(from.lookAtX, from.lookAtY, from.lookAtZ));
                tools.orbit.update();
            })
            .onComplete(function() {
                props.camera.position.set(to.x, to.y, to.z);
                tools.orbit.target.copy(new THREE.Vector3(to.lookAtX, to.lookAtY, to.lookAtZ));
                tools.orbit.update();

                resolve();
            })
            .start();
    });
};
```

**For a visual reference**, I am effectively trying to recreate something like the globe [here](https://www.fonterra.com/nz/en/campaign/from-here-to-everywhere.html#/home) and the animation that happens when you click one of the green markers, but with my globe rotating the entire time.

Also welcome to any suggestions if repositioning the camera isn't the best way to achieve the effect I'm looking for.

**FYI** - I originally posted this question on the Three.js discourse [here](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/tween-an-autorotating-camera-orbitcontrols-from-point-a-to-point-b/13247/1) but felt it would be useful to also post here.

Comment: Have you thought about rotating the scene and not the camera, or is that not going to achieve the same effect? 
e.g. set an object3d() at the world center and add all meshes to that object

Comment: @danlong I feel like that might work (it would be the same effect as just manually rotating the globe i.e, `globe.rotation.y += 0.1` in the render loop) but the problem is I ideally want to use `OrbitControls` as it has everything like dragging and damping already built in so I don't have to waste time effectively rewriting `OrbitControls`

Comment: @danlong I just added a visual reference underneath my code so you can get a better idea of the effect I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Ah OK, I see what you mean. I'll comment if I think of something else